# returning the grpc status code in case of success

Tags: go, grpc

I have a grpc handler `Something(ctx context.Context, request *protocol.Something) (*pb.Test, error)`

I return errors like `return nil, status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "something wrong")`

In case of success. I always return nil `return test, nil`, although there is code `0`. Do I have to return the code on success? `return test, status.New(codes.OK, "OK")`

Answer (score 3):

Per [doc](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html) - return code `0` means `not an error; returned on success.`

| Code | Number | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OK | 0 | Not an error; returned on success. |

Through `return test, nil`, the nil in the error, means there is no error, and   `OK` is returned on success

```
    // OK is returned on success.
    OK Code = 0
```

---

As you mentioned in the question, `return test, status.New(codes.OK, "OK")`, actually, the [`status.New()`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/status/status.go#L48) just return `Status` rather than `error`, it could be failed in the function `Something`.

You may use [`status.Error(codes.OK, "OK")`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/status/status.go#L58) which return `error`. However, if `codes.OK` is passed in, returns `nil`. It is the same behavior as return `nil` directly.

Source code

```golang
// Error returns an error representing c and msg.  If c is OK, returns nil.
func Error(c codes.Code, msg string) error {
    return New(c, msg).Err()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to do that - no need to return the status code ok on success